# create child entity and move properties down the entity hierarchy

Tags: ios, core-data, xcode6

In apple [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Articles/vmLightweightMigration.html) it says like this regarding the lightweight migration:

> You can create a new parent or child entity and move properties up and down the entity hierarchy

Do any one know how to make that when i have entity Car with property BodyPaint and i want to add child entity Body and move the BodyPaint to the Body so i have

`Car` 
     -> `BodyPaint`

but want 
    `Car` 
-> `Body` 
      ->    `Paint`

And the Paint value is taken form BodyPaint

EDIT: 
So I think I was misunderstood. 
I have coredata model 1 and want to change it in model 2 the way I described. BodyPaint is a property of car and i want to make it property of Body and the Body should be a relation one to one to Car.

Thanks M.

Answer (score 0):

You can set entity in core-data(`xcdatamodeld` file's Data Model Inspector) as Abstract entity with any common properties that the child entities will inherit. All the child entities will have that Abstract entity as their parent entity. All these child entities will inherit the attributes of the parent entity.

Example:

Entity: Car (Abstract)
Properties: paint,... etc

Entity: BMW-xx (Parent: Car)
Properties: airbag, ....etc

Now on a `BMW-xx` instance(NSManagedObject) you can access `paint` property of `Car` class

Comment: This is not what i want to achieve... I want to be able to create an instance of car just want to move some of the properties to another entity that i could also use elsewhere.

Comment: You can only access the property on an instance of `Car` or of its Child (Subclass).

Answer (score 0):

1. Create entity `Car`.
2. Create entity `Body`.
3. Create entity `Paint`.
4. Add relation `cbody` to entity `Car` which points to `Body`.
5. Add relations `bpaint` to entity `Body` which points to `Paint`.
6. Use properties in the form of `carObject.cbody.bpaint.color`. Here `carObject` is an instance of `Car` entity and `color` is one of the `Paint's` properties.